# SQL Server CASE function only returns first value in string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the `CASE` command to simply change a substring query result from a number to a name.

Things seem to work fine but I am having a hard time trying to figure out why the results only display the first value of the string.

```
Declare @OverrideON INT, @OverrideOFF INT 
SET @OverrideON = 1  SET @OverrideOFF = 0

SELECT LonDeviceName,
CASE  WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,65,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'Fan In Override' 
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,67,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'HW In Override'    
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,69,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'CHW In Override'
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,71,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'OAD In Override'
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,73,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'VFD In Override'
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,65,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'Fan Normal' 
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,67,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'HW Normal'    
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,69,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'CHW Normal'
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,71,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'OAD Normal'
      WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,73,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'VFD Normal'
      ELSE '**StringError**'
END as 'Manual Overrides'
FROM dbo.Points
WHERE LogicName like '%override%'
```

When the code is run it creates a column titled `Manual Overrides` which is correct, in that column it displays the first value within the string. But, where are the results for the other four values within the string. Any assistance or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: CASE is not a statement, it is an expression that returns a single value. It will never return 2 or more values from within your string. Can you show a simplified version of your data, and desired results?

Comment: Why not create a ManualOverrides table so you don't have to modify this query every time you get a new one?

Comment: Would you need the values concatenated on the same row or four different rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT LonDeviceName,
    CASE  WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,65,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'In Override'
          WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,65,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'Normal'
          ELSE '**StringError**'
    END as 'Fan',
    CASE  WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,67,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'In Override' 
          WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,67,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'Normal'
          ELSE '**StringError**'
    END as 'HW',
    CASE  WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,69,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'In Override'
          WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,69,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'Normal'
          ELSE '**StringError**'
    END as 'CHW',
    CASE  WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,71,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'In Override'
          WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,71,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'Normal'
          ELSE '**StringError**'
    END as 'OAD',
    CASE  WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,73,1) = @OverrideON  THEN 'In Override'
          WHEN SUBSTRING (PointValue,73,1) = @OverrideOFF THEN 'Normal'
          ELSE '**StringError**'
    END as 'VFD'
FROM dbo.Points
WHERE LogicName like '%override%'
```

Comment: Thanks @RedFilter This works exactly as I had planned. 99% done here, now I have to change that where clause to only show the rows 'In Override'. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need these bulky variables to represent 1 and 0? Really? Anyway, really guessing at what you want for output here. Maybe this:

```
SELECT LonDeviceName, [Manual Overrides] = '' 
    + 'Fan '  + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,65,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + ',HW '  + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,67,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + ',CHW ' + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,69,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + ',OAD ' + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,71,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + ',VFD ' + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,73,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
FROM dbo.Points
WHERE LogicName LIKE '%override%';
```

Or maybe you only want to see the values that are actually in override:

```
SELECT LonDeviceName, [Manual Overrides] = '' 
    + 'Fan '  + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,65,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE '' END
    + ',HW '  + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,67,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE '' END
    + ',CHW ' + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,69,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE '' END
    + ',OAD ' + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,71,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE '' END
    + ',VFD ' + CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,73,1) 
                WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE '' END
FROM dbo.Points
WHERE LogicName LIKE '%override%';
```

Or maybe you want separate columns after all:

```
SELECT LonDeviceName, 
    + [Fan] = CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,65,1) 
              WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + [HW]  = CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,67,1) 
              WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + [CHW] = CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,69,1) 
              WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + [OAD] = CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,71,1) 
              WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
    + [VFD] = CASE SUBSTRING (PointValue,73,1) 
              WHEN '1' THEN 'In Override' ELSE 'Normal' END
FROM dbo.Points
WHERE LogicName LIKE '%override%';
```

Or maybe something different entirely. It's tough to bridge the gap from the query you wrote to the results you want if we can't see the source data or the results you want.